# How to set image via innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Confusing question...

In echo i have blank page.. if i set innerHTML="some text"; - it works. Why it's not working with image? If i directly goes to https://domain.com/adv/banner.jpg it will open image...

```
echo'
  <div id="yabanner"></div>

  <script>
  yaGetBanner();
  function yaGetBanner()
  {
    var el = document.getElementById("yabanner");
    el.innerHTML="<img src=\'https://domain.com/adv/banner.jpg\' width=\'400px\' height=\'150px\'>";
  }
  </script>
  ';
```

Comment: try with relative path once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `double quotes` for the `img` attribute too, and then you need the `backslashes`. So your code would look like:

```
echo '
<div id="yabanner"></div>

<script>
yaGetBanner();
function yaGetBanner()
{
   var el = document.getElementById("yabanner");
   el.innerHTML="<img src=\"http://placehold.it/350x350\" width=\"400px\" height=\"150px\">";
}
</script>';
```

> Also note that you have `banner` and `adv` in the name of your image URL. Adblockers will block these images or add `inline` styling to your `img` attributes containing that image.

I hope this help!

Comment: i'm on echo' '; how can i remove quotes.. it's php file

Comment: @iSeeDev See updated answer please :)

Comment: ok. what i have now. i tried open page code, and found that someone added this attributes to div.. wtf?

<img src="https://yaskidki.ru/adv/banner.jpg" width="0" height="0" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 0px 0px;">

i didn't add that attributes.. i simply 

el.innerHTML="<img src=\"https://yaskidki.ru/adv/banner.jpg\">";

Comment: @iSeeDev It's your adblocker, it's blocking the image because of the word `adv` and `banner.jpg`

Comment: ahahaha!!! THATS REAL! this is the problem)) Thx allot for help) adblock off and it's works)) thx)))

Comment: @iSeeDev Your welcome haha! :-)

Comment: @C0dekid put that in your answer, I'll up it

Comment: Here you go, and thank you! :-) @zer00ne

Comment: Attribute values can be single quoted, they don't have to be double quoted.

Comment: @Oriol I know, but It is inside a `PHP` single quote echo, that's why he need to use the double quotes.

Comment: @C0dekid Do you mean PHP can't echo single quotes? In the question they are properly escaped.

Comment: @Oriol depends on what echo method you use, example 1: `echo 'Hello M'oneil'` will result in parse error while example 2: `echo 'Hello M\'oneil'` wil output: **Hello M'oneil**. Also the same for double quotes.