# Angular: How to include an image tag inside a div when using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a div containing an innerHTML tag and another image tag but for some reason, the image isn't displayed. How to resolve it?

```
<div *ngIf="pname" innerHTML="{{ (data.att.val && data.att.val.name) ? data.att.val.name : pname }}">
   <img alt="Card" src="../../../assets/link.ico" style="height: 14px; vertical-align: super;">
</div>
```

Here the img tag is not rendering if innerHTML is in use but works fine without it. The reason for using innerHTML is because some of the fields contain HTML tags and I want to render them as HTML

Comment: If you use `innerHTML` you are telling it what the contents will be.  You shouldn't be using both.

Comment: You could throw a `<span>` in there before the image, and put the `innerHTML` on it

Comment: if you're using `*ngIf` for conditional rendering, why are you still using `innerHTML` wiith conditional content? I feel like you aren't trying to solve something here, but instead creating a problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set image via innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36859062/how-to-set-image-via-innerhtml)

Comment: @Takatalvi I ultimately moved the conditional check to ts and returned the innerHTML content including the img tag similar to the above solution

Comment: And I guess it works... or still having the doubt?